# Convert DataTable to list

Tags: c#, list, linq, datatable

I have this DataTAble

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("A");
dt.Columns.Add("B");
dt.Rows.Add("1", "5");
dt.Rows.Add("6", "10");
dt.Rows.Add("11", "15");
```

How can I convert this DataTable to get a list like this

```
List<string> dtList= new List<string> { "1", "5", "6", "10", "11", "15" };
```

Comment: Did you try anything? What issue you are facing with that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SelectMany`:

```
List<string> dtList= dt.AsEnumerable()
    .SelectMany(r=> new[]{ r.Field<string>("A"), r.Field<string>("B") })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: that's perfect, thank you :) also the @Thierry V works perfectly, but I am accepting this answer for data type specification, thank you both of you

Answer (score 2):

Convert to `DataRow[]` first by `Select`, then `SelectMany` to flatten to an array of object. Finally, convert each value `object` to `string`

```
var list = dt.Select().SelectMany(row => row.ItemArray).Select(x=> (string)x).ToList()
```

Comment: `dt.Select()` creates a new `DataRow[]`(not a list), but i'd use `AsEnumerable` which doesn't create a new collection, hence saves memory and CPU.

Comment: I'm pretty sure thats the 2nd occurrence of this comment.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("A");
    dt.Columns.Add("B");
    dt.Rows.Add("1", "5");
    dt.Rows.Add("6", "10");
    dt.Rows.Add("11", "15");
    var output = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().SelectMany(x => new[] { x[0], x[1] }).ToList();
```

Edit: added .ToList();

Comment: Creates a `List<Object>` not `List<string>`

Answer (score 1):

I know its too late

but you can use this way with help of Newtonsoft Json:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataTable);
var YourConvertedDataType = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourDataType>(json);
```